# ControlBlock member of weak_ptr

Tags: c++, oop, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, weak-ptr

So I've been reading about shared_ptr/weak_ptr implementation and I do not get a small detail. As far as I understand, there is a class ControlBlock defined in the private section of shared_ptr. But weak_ptr also stores a pointer to some ControlBlock instance. In my implementation should I befriend weak_ptr inside shared_ptr or define ControlBlock outside shared_ptr as a struct?

Comment: You are trying to implement shared_ptr and weak_ptr, is that correct?

Comment: Correct. I am trying to resolve cyclic dependencies.

Comment: Which of the two options works for you?

Comment: The first would be better in terms of code style and encapsulation, but I highly doubt that standard implementations make weak_ptr a friend of shared_ptr.

Comment: Forward declares are often used to get around these sort of issues. Like somewhere there will be a class called this, but don't worry I'm only using a pointer/reference here so I don't need to know about it until later

Comment: Standard implementations would absolutely make weak_ptr friends with shared_ptr if it helped them. However I just looked up how Microsoft's library does it, and it's a class called std::_Ref_count_base which is not defined in weak_ptr or shared_ptr. Names belonging with _ and a capital letter are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Could you share the link please?

Comment: @AmirMokhammed-Ali -- since both `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` need to access the same data, it makes sense for the type of that data to stand on its own. Putting it inside `std::shared_ptr` would mean that the code for `std::shared_ptr` would use the (made up) name `control_block`, while the code for `std::weak_ptr` would use the name `std::weak_ptr<whatever_my_type_is>::control_block`. Yes, you could encapsulate that in a typedef, but that doesn't really help: the two templates traffic in the **same** type but with two **different** names.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.